# Securing files against malware

Tags: security, malware

Let's say, somehow a malware is present on your filesystem (e.g : [BusyWinman Malware](http://bulletins.it.ubc.ca/archives/30465)).

How would you secure your files against being transfered by such a malware to somewhere else?
Please, describe the most restrictive case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a malware has made it through your system, the system must be considered compromised and unreliable.

Therefore any mitigation countermeasure, e.g. blocking connections to specific IPs, is unsafe. Unless you reverse-engineered the malware **and** have acquired a perfect understanding of how it works, you can never be sure it won't pop up something bad again one day.

The only good option is to reformat your machine i.e. *"nuke it from orbit"*, and reinstall again.

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided gives the recommended remediation for this malware. There are no further instructions because the malware is not understood. To stop it from taking hold, and prevent it from accessing or sending files, it will need to be disassembled and understood.

> Identify infected machines using the Indicators of Compromise
>   provided. Since the malware is not fully understood, we recommend
>   installing a clean version of the required OS on a new drive and
>   selectively copying necessary files from the infected drive.

Blocking ingoing and outgoing connections to and from the hardcoded IP addresses at the firewall may or may not work.